# How to check if JZMQ socket is connected

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

Is there way to check if JZMQ (java binding of zmq) socket is connected?

```
ZContext zmqContext = new ZContext();
ZMQ.Socket workerSocket = zmqContext.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
workerSocket.setIdentity("ID".getBytes());
workerSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
```

After code above I would like to check if workerSocket is connected. It would be nice to check connection status.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's no method in the API to check if a socket is connected.

ZeroMq abstracts the network; client and server connections are completely transparent to the peer making the connection. A client or server may send messages to non-existent peers; no errors will be generated; instead, they'll queue up in socket buffers based on HWM config.

To check for peer availability, do it manually using a synchronous request/reply heartbeat with a timeout factor; here's an example, hope it helps!

Check out samples for request/reply here!
https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/

Comment: The link is dead. Maybe you could add a little sample in your answer? :) This is the blog entry in googles cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ty68WXOpHXEJ:od-eon.com/blogs/stefan/checking-availability-zeromq-endpoint/+&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk

Comment: thx, updated link: If you're looking for basic request/reply examples, there are many for different target languages, see here: https://github.com/imatix/zguide/tree/master/examples/, examples prefixed with `rr` denote request/reply samples

Comment: Thanks, personally I am not, I can ususlly google that myself, but I came across this and noticed the link, so I thought you would want to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think I found a trick that works for me to check if a socket is connected. The best solution to your client side is to create a socket poller and poll on the pull socket until a message is received. This avoids wasteful sleeps, and makes for generally tighter code:

Here is the code that do the works:

```
 private void blockUntilConnected() {
        ZMQ.Poller poller = ctx.createPoller(1);
        poller.register(this.subscriber, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
        int rc = -1;
        while (rc == -1) {
            rc = poller.poll(1000);
        }
        poller.pollin(0);
    }
```

I will also supply the full source code:

Server Part:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.zeromq.SocketType;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import static io.Adrestus.config.ConsensusConfiguration.*;

public class ConsensusServer {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsensusServer.class);

    private final ZContext ctx;
    private final String IP;
    private final ZMQ.Socket publisher;
    private final ZMQ.Socket collector;


    public ConsensusServer(String IP) {
        this.IP = IP;
        this.ctx = new ZContext();
        this.publisher = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.PUB);
        this.publisher.setHeartbeatIvl(2);
        this.collector = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.PULL);

        this.publisher.bind("tcp://" + IP + ":" + PUBLISHER_PORT);
        this.collector.bind("tcp://" + IP + ":" + COLLECTOR_PORT);
        this.collector.setReceiveTimeOut(CONSENSUS_TIMEOUT);
        this.publisher.setSendTimeOut(CONSENSUS_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public ConsensusServer() {
        this.IP = findIP();
        this.ctx = new ZContext();
        this.publisher = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.PUB);
        this.collector = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.PULL);

        this.publisher.bind("tcp://" + IP + ":" + PUBLISHER_PORT);
        this.collector.bind("tcp://" + IP + ":" + COLLECTOR_PORT);
        this.publisher.setSendTimeOut(CONSENSUS_TIMEOUT);
        this.collector.setReceiveTimeOut(CONSENSUS_TIMEOUT);
    }


    private String findIP() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));
            return socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Make sure you intern connection is working");
    }

    public void publishMessage(byte[] data) {
        publisher.send(data, 0);
    }

    public byte[] receiveData() {
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = collector.recv();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("Socket Closed");
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static Logger getLOG() {
        return LOG;
    }

    public static void setLOG(Logger LOG) {
        ConsensusServer.LOG = LOG;
    }

    public ZContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public String getIP() {
        return IP;
    }

    public ZMQ.Socket getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public ZMQ.Socket getCollector() {
        return collector;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.publisher.close();
        this.collector.close();
        this.ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Client Part:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.zeromq.SocketType;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

import static io.Adrestus.config.ConsensusConfiguration.*;

public class ConsensusClient {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsensusClient.class);
    private final String IP;
    private ZContext ctx;
    private final ZMQ.Socket subscriber;
    private final ZMQ.Socket push;


    public ConsensusClient(String IP) {
        this.ctx = new ZContext();
        this.IP = IP;
        this.subscriber = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.SUB);
        this.push = ctx.createSocket(SocketType.PUSH);
        this.subscriber.connect("tcp://" + IP + ":" + SUBSCRIBER_PORT);
        this.subscriber.subscribe(ZMQ.SUBSCRIPTION_ALL);
        this.subscriber.setReceiveTimeOut(CONSENSUS_TIMEOUT);
        blockUntilConnected();
        this.push.connect("tcp://" + IP + ":" + COLLECTOR_PORT);
    }


    private void blockUntilConnected() {
        ZMQ.Poller poller = ctx.createPoller(1);
        poller.register(this.subscriber, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
        int rc = -1;
        while (rc == -1) {
            rc = poller.poll(1000);
        }
        poller.pollin(0);
    }

    public void pushMessage(byte[] data) {
        push.send(data);
    }

    public byte[] receiveData() {
        byte[] data = subscriber.recv();
        return data;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.subscriber.close();
        this.push.close();
        this.ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Main part: (**Notice** that the client is first initialized and it's blocked until a server is started and connected. You can simply add a timeout if you don't want to hang on forever)

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class CustomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //client already started and block until server is connected
        (new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ConsensusClient Client = new ConsensusClient("localhost");
                while (true) {
                    byte[] res = Client.receiveData();
                    System.out.println(new String(res));
                }
            }
        }).start();


        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //server started
        ConsensusServer Server = new ConsensusServer("localhost");

        Thread.sleep(100);
        Server.publishMessage("Message".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Server.publishMessage("Message".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Server.publishMessage("Message".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        Server.close();
    }

}
```