# ZeroMQ: Is there no other way than polling or sleep to check if a socket is connected?

Tags: c, zeromq

We are using ZeroMQ for a project, with the following architecture:
[image]

This is basically our module we wrote in C for using ZeroMQ:

```
#define PUB_ADDR "ipc:///tmp/broker_frontend"
#define SUB_ADDR "ipc:///tmp/broker_backend"
#define PUB_MON_ADDR "inproc://monitor-publisher"
#define SUB_MON_ADDR "inproc://monitor-subscriber"

#define RET_ERROR(x) syslog(LOG_ERR, x "%s", zmq_strerror(errno)); cleanupZMQ(); return false;

static zmq_ctx_t ctx = NULL;
static zmq_sock_t pub_sock = NULL;
static zmq_sock_t sub_sock = NULL;
static zmq_sock_t sub_mon_sock = NULL;
static zmq_sock_t pub_mon_sock = NULL;

static char* subscriptions[] = { REQ_TOPIC };
static size_t subscriptions_count = (sizeof(subscriptions) / sizeof(subscriptions[0]));

static inline void cleanupZMQ() {
    if (pub_sock) {
        zmq_close(pub_sock);
    }

    if (sub_sock) {
        zmq_close(sub_sock);
    }

    if (sub_mon_sock) {
        zmq_close(sub_mon_sock);
    }

    if (pub_mon_sock) {
        zmq_close(pub_mon_sock);
    }

    if (ctx) {
       zmq_ctx_destroy(ctx);
    }
}

static bool waitForConnect(zmq_sock_t monitor) {
    zmq_msg_t msg;

    bool ret = true;
    bool connected = false;
    bool handshaked = false;
    do {
        zmq_msg_init(&msg);
        int rc = zmq_msg_recv(&msg, monitor, 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not receive first frame from monitor: ")
        }
        uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*)zmq_msg_data(&msg);
        uint16_t event = *((uint16_t*)data);
        uint32_t value = *((uint32_t*)data+2);

        zmq_msg_init(&msg);
        rc = zmq_msg_recv(&msg, monitor, 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not receive second frame from monitor: ")
        }
        char* addr = (char*)zmq_msg_data(&msg);
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Event: %u, Value: %u, Addr: %s", event, value, addr);
        if (event == ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED) {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Connected to '%s'.", addr);
            connected = true;
        } else if (event == ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_DELAYED) {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Connecting delayed!");
        } else if (event == ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED) {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Connecting retried!");
        } else if ((event == ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_NO_DETAIL)
            || (event == ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL)
            || (event == ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_AUTH)) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error! Handshake with '%s' failed: %s", addr, zmq_strerror(value));
            handshaked = true;
            ret = false;
        } else if (event == ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_SUCCEEDED) {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Handshake with '%s' succeded.", addr);
            handshaked = true;
            ret = true;
        } else {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Unexpected event: %u", event);
        }
    } while(!(connected && handshaked));

    zmq_msg_close(&msg);
    return ret;
}

bool startZMQ() {
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
        if (ctx == NULL) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not open ZMQ context: ");
        }
    } else {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "ZMQ is already started.");
    }

    if (sub_sock == NULL) {
        sub_sock = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_SUB);
        if (sub_sock == NULL) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not open ZMQ sub socket: ");
        }

        if (zmq_socket_monitor(sub_sock, SUB_MON_ADDR, ZMQ_EVENT_ALL)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not monitor ZMQ sub socket: ");
        }

        sub_mon_sock = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
        if (sub_mon_sock == NULL) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not open ZMQ sub-monitor socket: ");
        }

        if (zmq_connect(sub_mon_sock, SUB_MON_ADDR)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not connect ZMQ sub-monitor socket: ");
        }

        for (size_t i=0; i<subscriptions_count; i++) {
            if (zmq_setsockopt(sub_sock, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, subscriptions[i], strlen(subscriptions[i]))) {
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error! Can not subscribe to topic '%s': %s", subscriptions[i], zmq_strerror(errno));
            } else {
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "Subscribed to '%s'.", subscriptions[i]);
            }
        }

        if (zmq_connect(sub_sock, SUB_ADDR)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not connect ZMQ sub socket: ");
        }
        waitForConnect(sub_mon_sock);
    } else {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Subscriber socket is already open.");
    }

    if (pub_sock == NULL) {
        pub_sock = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_PUB);
        if (pub_sock == NULL) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not open ZMQ pub socket: ");
        }

        if (zmq_socket_monitor(pub_sock, PUB_MON_ADDR, ZMQ_EVENT_ALL)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not monitor ZMQ pub socket: ");
        }

        pub_mon_sock = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
        if (pub_mon_sock == NULL) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not open ZMQ pub-monitor socket: ");
        }

        if (zmq_connect(pub_mon_sock, PUB_MON_ADDR)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not connect ZMQ pub-monitor socket: ");
        }

        if (zmq_connect(pub_sock, PUB_ADDR)) {
            RET_ERROR("Error! Can not connect ZMQ pub socket: ");
        }

        waitForConnect(pub_mon_sock);
    } else {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "Publisher socket is already open.");
    }

    sleep(3);
    return true;
}

size_t sendZMQMsg(const char* topic, size_t topic_len, const msg_buffer_t msg, size_t msg_len) {
    size_t sended = 0;
    int rc = zmq_send(pub_sock, topic, topic_len, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    if (rc < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error! Could not send ZMQ topic: %s", zmq_strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    sended += rc;
    rc = zmq_send(pub_sock, msg, msg_len, 0);
    if (rc < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error! Could not send ZMQ message: %s", zmq_strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }
    sended += rc;
    return sended;
}

void endZMQ() {
    cleanupZMQ();
}
```

As you can see, we had to add an `sleep(3)` at the end of our `startZMQ()` function. Without this the first few messages sent would get lost.

Of course we know about this 'slow joiner syndrome'. We ensure that the broker is ready before connecting anything to it and the subscribers are connected (also with the three second delay) before the publishers. But still, we have to wait these three seconds before the publishers can use their sockets.
The publishers and subscribers do not know each other due to the central broker and we do not want that they have to connect directly to each other, since we have a lot of both parts and if anyone had to directly connect to anyone else, the system would basically unmaintainable.

We found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442970/zeromq-have-to-sleep-before-send) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184841/how-to-check-if-jzmq-socket-is-connected) and of course we read the [Guide](https://zguide.zeromq.org/), especially this [Part](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Node-Coordination), where in the guide themself a `sleep(1)` was used and than a polling with a second socket-pair is recommended.
Is there really no other way in this library to check if your socket is ready, than polling it?

As you can see we already catching the zmq-events in our `waitForConnect` function using zmq-monitor-sockets. Should this not be enough? Are we missing something here?

Comment: One of the most frustrating things I find with ZeroMQ is it really doesn't have a concept of "connected" like you do in TCP/IP. Instead you just send data and if it gets to the destination, then it's connected. In practice this means you need to do frequent testing/heartbeat signalling to ensure you're still effectively connected.

Comment: So there is really no way that ZeroMQ tells you: "socket connected"? Not even with the events? This is insane! For what is this 'ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED' than even useful?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you're limited by the fact that tcp (which underpins ZMQ) is buffered. ZMQ does a lot of ensure that messages sent are delivered (heartbeat, whole message delivery, etc), so long at the connection is live, but it doesn't solve all problems.

tcp and ZMQ both implement "Actor Model"; data sent is buffered by the transport. The sender can return from a send(), before the recipient has called recv(). If you want an absolute guarantee of delivery (or confirmation that it's not made it), you need to have some sort of ack message being transferred back to the sender.

What you then end up with then is Communicating Sequential Processes. This is Actor Model, but the connection between sender and recipient does not buffer the data being transferred. The send() does not complete until the recipient's recv() has completed. This serves as an execution rendezvous (the act of sending means your code knows whereabouts in its execution it has got to - namely recv() has completed). This is particularly useful if you have a (quasi) real time requirement; your sender can know if the recipient isn't keeping up!

CSP is implemented in Go and Rust - it's kinda coming back into fashion.

==EDIT==

With multi-stage patterns like this, the best thing to do is to have "readiness" ripple from the end back towards the start. I've often done this with explicit messaging to create such an execution rendezvous, but you've indicated a desire not to have to do that.

So, you could:

1. have the proxy create and bind() its XPUB,
2. and then wait for the 3 subs to connect to it (using socket monitor to determine when that's happened - the ZMQ_EVENT_ACCEPTED event occurs 3 times). Execution Rendezvous #1 reached
3. Only then should the proxy create and bind() its own XSUB socket.
4. The individual publishers can create and connect() at any time (remember, connect() returns immediately, regardless),
5. but the publishers should use socket monitor to determine when they've actually got a connection to the proxy before starting their main loop (each waits until socket monitor reports a ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED event). Execution rendezvous #2 reached.

The only flaw is if you want all the publishers to block until all are connected to the proxy. The only way of achieving that is with some other interconnectivity (e.g. a PUB on the proxy SUBscribed to by the publishers explicitly to receive a "go" message). With such execution rendezvous, one is fundamentally limited by the fact that tcp / ip buffers data everywhere, so the "go" message isn't going to arrive everywhere at exactly the same time; that likely matters only for the most severe of real time requirements. However, by doing everything from the end to the start, one does at least guarantee that processes reach readiness in the right order.

By the way, your code snippet omits the proxy shown in the figure.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. We are just looking for a way to ensure, that a with ZeroMQ opened socket is connected and ready for usage. The delay is obviously unreliable (nobody grantees you that the three seconds are enough, maybe sometimes five seconds are needed to establish the connection). Some way/mechanic from ZeroMQ to tell you that. the socket is connected.

The polling way is hardly doable for us because of our architecture with the broker. The broker would lost its transparency if it has to make an handshake with every publisher and subscriber.

Comment: @cone1018 Ah, apologies. I've expanded the answer I gave, showing how you can achieve execution rendezvous in an end-to-start manner for your system starting up.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications.
The problem is, we do not know how many publishers and subscribers we will have. They come and go. This is the whole reason for the broker, everyone just connects to a central node and does not have to know anyone else.

What do you mean by "omits the proxy shown in the figure"? I have added the address we are using to connect to the broker. Should I also post the code for the broker?

Comment: @cone1018, I see. Thing is, there's no conceptual difference betweeen "a late starter" and "they come and go". The former is just a minor variant of the latter. Neither ZMQ or any other software can spot the difference. You either have to have some pre-defined configuration as input ("there will be 3 pubs and 4 subs, and we'll wait for all connections to come up"), or an agreed cut-off time ("if a node hasn't joined inside 3 seconds, tough luck"), or the flowing messages are ephemeral (like a TV transmission - you can pick up the program part way through).

Comment: @cone1018 Basically, the broker cannot tell the differnece between something that's late connecting and something that's never going to connect. It needs more information.